# Injecting controllers as services in typescript/angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm, angularjs-scope, typescript

I need to share data between 2 controllers. For this, as I have learnt here on SO, a common contract between the 2 controllers is necessary - a service.

```
export interface IController1Service {
    sharedItem : any;
}

class Controller1Service implements IController1Service {
    sharedItem : any;
}

export class Controller1 {

    constructor(contract : IController1Service) {
        contract.sharedItem = "Hi Controller2!";
    }

}

export class Controller2 {

    constructor(contract: IController1Service) {
        alert(contract.sharedItem);
    }

}
```

Now this works all fine etc. But I wondered if it's really necessary to create a separate service class and inject it into both controllers just to share a simple variable? Isn't it possible to let 1 controller implement the service and then inject it into the other?

```
export interface IController1Service {
    sharedItem: any;
}

export class Controller1 implements IController1Service {
    sharedItem: any;

    constructor() {
        this.sharedItem = "Hi Controller2!";
    }
}
```

I tried, however angular greets me with a

```
Can't resolve dependency for controller MyApp.Controller2 with name MyServices.IController1Service
```

Answer (score 1):

Services are global singletons. They can be injected into both controllers and each controller will access the same service and therefore the same variable within that service. This is not the same with controllers. Multiple instances of the same controller can be created.

You can't use DI to inject a specific instance of a controller. You could inject the $controller service into controller1 and then create an instance of a controller2 within controller1. But that, of course is not what you want. It would not be the same instance of the controller that contains the variable that you want to access.

The fact that creating a dependency between two controllers is not directly supported should be a hint that this may not be something you want to do. Controllers should only contain the business logic for a single view.  The documentation specifically states that they should not be used to share state across controllers. Doing so not only complicates your code but make testing difficult.